# GETOPTS passing option to create find function

Tags: linux, arguments, getopts

Im trying desperately finding the solution for my Getopts
For example

```
#!/bin/bash

while getopts ":a:b:" opt; do

case $opt in 

  a) find / $OPTARG >&2  ;;

  b) 2>/dev/null  >&2 ;;

  \?)
    echo "Invalid option: -$OPTARG" >&2
    exit 1
    ;;
esac
```

and then as output example

> ./somefile.sh -a *txt -b

or

> ./somefile.sh -b -a *txt

but then i want to make sure i can upgrade it further, for examples find only sh files, or
something else.
Its not easy to find, but i hope someone could help me.

Comment: can you explain what you want to achieve when **-a XXX** is passed?